# Spelling or Saying Words Differently to Create a Rhyme

Tags: rhymes

What is the name for wordplay in which a word is spoken or spelled differently to make a rhyme? For example:

> I'm running this shit you should try *tacklin*',
>   Lil Wayne in one word *immaculin* [immaculate]
>
> -Rick Ross ft. T-Pain, Lil Wayne, and Kanye West, "Maybach Music 2"

Comment: Poetic licence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wiktionary defines [forced rhyme](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forced_rhyme) to mean exactly what you want.

However, other sources, such as this well-illustrated article on [Rhymezone](https://forum.rhymezone.com/articles/963-forced-rhymes-what-they-are-and-how-to-avoid-them) give a more general definition that includes other dubious, but just as pertinent, ways to make a rhyme.

Answer (score 0):

Alliteration? -- although I don't think the words are necessarily spelled differently, but the words must just sound similar phonetically ... not sure. Homonyms sound the same but are spelled differently. (pair - pear).
But yes, poetic licence sounds about right in this case.

Comment: Alliteration is unrelated.